# Pixi.js can't load images because Django "can't find them"

Tags: javascript, django, pixi.js

I am sorry if the question seems a little bit confusing, but I couldn't find a better way to phrase it.
I am not very experienced in web development, and as I was trying to develop a game I run into an error I can't seem to fix.

I started developing by starting with the front-end, and when I had my game running I tried to move to the back-end, so I can implement leaderboards and users.
I am using Pixi.js, a javascript framework to help me developing the game. I use some images in the game and Pixi has a loader, which was working ok:

```
PIXI.loader
  .add([
    "images/quarter.png",
    "images/c_quarter.png",
    "images/clef.png",
    "images/heart.png"
  ])
  .on("progress", loadProgressHandler)
  .load(init);
```

When I moved to Django, I had to load my javascript using static files. However, images won't load using the Pixi loader, and I get the following error in my developer console:

```
quarter.png:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/images/quarter.png 404 (Not Found)
```

And this is what was happening in my server terminal:

```
Not Found: /game/images/quarter.png
[04/Dec/2016 13:38:49] "GET /game/images/quarter.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2146
Not Found: /game/images/c_quarter.png
Not Found: /game/images/heart.png
Not Found: /game/images/clef.png
[04/Dec/2016 13:38:49] "GET /game/images/c_quarter.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2152
[04/Dec/2016 13:38:49] "GET /game/images/clef.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2137
[04/Dec/2016 13:38:49] "GET /game/images/heart.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2140
```

I tried to load them using static files:

```
PIXI.loader
  .add([
    "{% static 'images/quarter.png' %}",
    "{% static 'images/c_quarter.png' %}",
    "{% static 'images/clef.png' %}",
    "{% static 'images/heart.png' %}"
  ])
  .on("progress", loadProgressHandler)
  .load(init);
```

And got the error:

```
c_quarter.png:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/c_quarter.png 404 (Not Found)
```

And in my server terminal:

```
[04/Dec/2016 13:27:22] "GET /game/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10074
[04/Dec/2016 13:27:22] "GET /static/game/js/ajax.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[04/Dec/2016 13:27:22] "GET /static/game/js/pixi.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[04/Dec/2016 13:27:22] "GET /static/game/js/pixi.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1682
[04/Dec/2016 13:27:22] "GET /static/images/c_quarter.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1673
[04/Dec/2016 13:27:22] "GET /static/images/clef.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1658
[04/Dec/2016 13:27:22] "GET /static/images/heart.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1661
[04/Dec/2016 13:27:22] "GET /static/images/quarter.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1667
```

I even pasted the images folder in lots of places just to make sure I was giving the correct path:

```
├── game
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── apps.pyc
│   ├── game
│   │   └── images
│   │       ├── c_quarter.png
│   │       ├── clef.png
│   │       ├── heart.png
│   │       └── quarter.png
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── c_quarter.png
│   │   ├── clef.png
│   │   ├── heart.png
│   │   └── quarter.png
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20161204_1240.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20161204_1240.pyc
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20161204_1244.py
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20161204_1244.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   └── game
│   │       ├── css
│   │       │   ├── bootstrap.css
│   │       │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │       │   └── business-frontpage.css
│   │       ├── fonts
│   │       │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│   │       │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│   │       │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│   │       │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│   │       │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
│   │       ├── images
│   │       │   ├── c_quarter.png
│   │       │   ├── clef.png
│   │       │   ├── heart.png
│   │       │   └── quarter.png
│   │       ├── imgs
│   │       │   └── main.jpg
│   │       └── js
│   │           ├── ajax.js
│   │           ├── bootstrap.js
│   │           ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │           ├── game
│   │           │   └── images
│   │           │       ├── c_quarter.png
│   │           │       ├── clef.png
│   │           │       ├── heart.png
│   │           │       └── quarter.png
│   │           ├── game.js
│   │           ├── jquery.js
│   │           ├── pixi.min.js
│   │           └── static
│   │               └── game
│   │                   └── images
│   │                       ├── c_quarter.png
│   │                       ├── clef.png
│   │                       ├── heart.png
│   │                       └── quarter.png
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── game
│   │       ├── images
│   │       │   ├── c_quarter.png
│   │       │   ├── clef.png
│   │       │   ├── heart.png
│   │       │   └── quarter.png
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
└── manage.py
```

If anyone can point me in right direction and help me correct this newbie error I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: did you read documentation on how django managing static files [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django should only serve assets from your *static* location. So in this case, you should be able to find the files by adding `game/` to the path.

```
PIXI.loader
  .add([
    "{% static 'game/images/quarter.png' %}",
    "{% static 'game/images/c_quarter.png' %}",
    "{% static 'game/images/clef.png' %}",
    "{% static 'game/images/heart.png' %}"
  ])
```

To make sure that your static assets are included when you do `collectstatic`, read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) to understand how this works. It's better to understand what is happening than to paste the files everywhere until it works.

> Files are searched by using the enabled finders. The default is to
>   look in all locations defined in STATICFILES_DIRS and in the 'static'
>   directory of apps specified by the INSTALLED_APPS setting.

So the common practice is to have a `static` folder inside each app that contains static assets. Those are then copied by django to the location where your static files will be served from.